# Choosing unsupervised learning algorithm for analyzing the spectrum of a linear operator

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra

I am a theoretical physicist, and new to CS.stackexchange, and have a little knowledge of CS, and in Machine Learning (only some general stuff). In physics we often analyze the spectrum of linear bound operators on finite dimensions, or simply try to understand the eigenspace of some matrix $M: v_j, \lambda_j$, where $M$ is a general square matrix of size $N\times N$ over the complex field, $v_j$ - is a right eigenvector with the corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda_j$.

Basically, in many cases we have a certain intuition (that comes through experience) about how to categorize $v_j, \lambda_j$ pairs in certain groups, however, as $N$ grows, and as one tunes certain parameters of the problem (affecting the matrix elements of $M$) - it becomes really hard to categorize all eigenstates. The question is: can I use unsupervised learning algorithms to analyze the eigenspace and obtain some information about it? For instance questions like: what number of different well-defined groups there are, and what kind of numbers can describe this group uniquely?

What looks as a problem to me as that the number of data points here is the same as the dimensionality of the problem - so there is very few data. May be some ML specialists that are enthusiastic about math used to deal with that a lot and have a ready-to-use recipe. Standard stuff like K-means, and such do not look like something that will work out here.

Thank you in advance, and hope the overall question makes sense.

**UPDATE:** A small remark I want to make is that the statement "the number of data points here is the same as the dimensionality of the problem" is true for the formulation of problem "as is". What I mean by that is that in principle we can think about every eigenvector as a complex-valued distribution function in a $k$-dimensional space, and then convert for each eigenvector $v_j$ it's $N$-complex-valued components into a smaller amount of meaningful characteristics such as, for example, "moments" of the distribution, or measure some correlations between the components of $v_j$, or something else... So the problem can be, actually, transformed into a different one, if required.

Comment: What do you mean by "categorize $v_j,\lambda_j$ pairs in certain groups"? What is your motivation (i.e. why do you need the spectrum and the categorization)? Do I understand correctly that you can find eigenvalues/vectors, but you don't know what to do with them next? "Standard stuff like K-means, and such do not look like something that will work out here" - why? I also don't understand why we need to know about data points: we have the matrix $M$, why do we need anything else?

Comment: I think you're going to need to make the questions more precise.  What does it mean to "analyze the eigenspace"?  What is a "group"?  What do you mean by "numbers [that] can describe this group uniquely"?  This all sounds fairly vague and open-ended to me, and I'm not sure exactly what you want such an algorithm to do.

Comment: Machine learning is not a panacea. Google maps doesn't use machine learning to find the shortest route to the destination. Music players don't use machine learning to convert MP3 files to sound. Operating systems don't use machine learning to schedule tasks.

Comment: Your question seems more appropriate to [datascience.se] or perhaps [scicomp.se].